# Node.js - Validate specific characters

Tags: node.js, validation, sequelize.js

To validate data in AZ sequelize use the following command.

```
ValidateMe sequelize.define var = ('Foo', {
   foo: {
     type: Sequelize.STRING,
     validate: {
       is: ["^ [az] + $", "i"], / / will only allow letters
}
```

I would like to include some specific characters like ("**`. / _ +`**"). How can I do?